# An external increment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a file "varstore.dat" (that does not exist prior to running this) that should initially contain the value 0. Then every time I execute the script, I want to increment this value by 1.

So essentially I am trying to create the file one time, read from the file, and then rewrite(or overwrite) the file upon each execution. However, my problem is that each time I run the program, it will always initialize to 0 and output 1. I am trying to rewrite into varstore.dat and for the new value to become the old value the next time I execute the script.

```
def get_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "a+") as f:
        val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(val))
        return val

your_counter = get_var_value()
print("This script has been run {} times.".format(your_counter))
```

Comment: Don't you need to `close()` the file?

Comment: @marekful You don't have to close the file with a context manager. `with ...`

Comment: When you open in "append" mode, the file position is set at the end of the file, so the `f.read` will always be an empty string.

Comment: @marekful Context managers manage their resources automatically.  In the case of using one to open a file like that, they close it once the execution leaves the code block.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do `f.seek(0)` before you get the `val`.

```
def get_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "a+") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(val))
    return val
```

The original code actually works in Python 2. Python2 opens the file(in `a+` mode) at `0` whereas Python3 opens it at the end(hence "append" mode). It appears that the reason it's different is because Python2 is based on C's `stdio.h`: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

http://bugs.python.org/msg229514

Comment: it might be better to move the return statement back 4 spaces too. I wonder will the file still be closed if the function returns with the context manager still open?

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I'm pretty sure it'll be closed, though, because it leaves the scope of the context manager.

Comment: Thanks Cody that worked! However, I don't quite understand how adding another seek fixed the problem

Comment: But why before and after getting val?

Comment: @ChenXie because `truncate` stops at the current location in the file, which is the line after your current input after you've read it into `val`.

Comment: @ChenXie You are opening the file at the end, so `f.read()` can't read anything, so you'll always get 0 from that expression.  Seeking to the beginning of the file first makes sure that you read in the file contents.  After you read that, you are parked back at the end of the file again, so you will just append instead of overwriting.  Seeking again puts you back at the start.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the file in `"a+"` mode (or any `a` mode), it puts the file position at the end of the file. To read it again you'd have to seek back to byte zero, as Cory Madden's answer suggests.

However, I don't understand why you're opening in `"a+"` mode if you're reading first, then overwriting. Just make two open calls.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(val))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `'a+'` mode that's being used to open the file. In Python 3, that mode starts you at the end of the file (where there's nothing left to read).

I'm not sure why it didn't work that way in Python 2. Instead it starts you at position 0 and warps you to the end of the file whenever you try to `write` to it (at least, that's how it works on my Windows system, the documentation suggests it may be OS dependent).

To make your code work correctly, you should use mode `'r+'` to open the file. That will allow you to both read and write the file from the beginning. And in fact, it might let you get rid of the `truncate()` call, since the new number you're going to be writing will always be at least as long as the number that was already in the file.